# I have taken a new role and I am not enjoying it

Tags: job-search, job-offer, new-job, stress, workload

I have recently started working for this large company mid of last year. I initially started as Accounts Payable officer. The bosses have recognised my work and they have offered me a position in a different team which they have mentioned would enhance my skills and I could learn more and I also have stated my interest on this position previously. I got the new position late last year and now I feel like I regret making that decision because I do not feel happy with what I am doing. There is so much mess that the other members have left and the current team has to fix them all and carry the burden. The "backlog" is consistent and it is not healthy - it is starting to affect my personal life because I have to stay back and even work after hours to catch up and clear the backlog which I think will never end. What do I do????

Comment: Never work more than your standard hours - ever.

Comment: ^ (unless you get paid for it)...right?

Find it hard to understand the exact problem without more detail. It sounds like you don't enjoy the new role because there is too much work, partially because of the state of the team.

I would just add don't always shy away from a challenge like that (dysfunctional team). You can learn a lot from what put the team in that situation in the first place, and if you fix everything then you can boast about it in interviews. 

If you run teams in the future then this kind of thing is good background. monotonous tickets, not so much.

Comment: You've fallen into the trap that I managed to avoid, last year: my boss asked me to go to another team, and I answered "Yes, I'd like to go there, but only when you agree that, in case I don't like it, I get the opportunity to come back.". My boss agreed to that condition, I went to the other department, I didn't like it, I re-called the boss about the promise he made, and I came back without any problem.

Answer (score 4):

Talk to your boss and say what you just told us. Say that you want to move, preferably back to where you were before.

If they do value you, they will see the danger that you might leave and will wish to retain you.

If they won’t move you, whether back or to a another department, then they don’t’ value you, you owe them no loyalty and should look out for number one, which sounds like it involves looking for another job.

It is possible that they just moved “the new guy” into “that job that no one wants to do”. Ask them, and find out.